# 180 degree rotated div is only clickable from one side

Tags: html, css

I've run into a rather strange problem. I have a div that is rotatable via CSS3. The div has a front div child and back div child, with the back div having `-webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg )` set.

The problem that once the parent element is rotated to display the back side of the div, it will only detect clicks of child elements on exactly one side of the div, specifically the second half of the div or right side. The front side div detects clicks on the entire face of element. Also, the z-indexes are fine. I assume that the issue may be due to the rotation and the browser displaying one half of the side "closer"?

The code that this is breaking is extremely complex, so I created a test file to demonstrate the problem below. I'm using a jQuery plugin I wrote for the 3D transformations, which can be found here https://github.com/pwhisenhunt/jquery.transform/blob/master/jquery.transform.js.

**Edit:** After experimentation, the clicking of the button element is only registering from 100-200px and not from 0-100px. In other words, it is in fact only registering on the second half of the div.

Any help is very much appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .element{
            width:200;
            height:200;

            -webkit-perspective: 800;
            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }

        .element figure {
          display: block;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            border:1px solid yellow;
        }

        .element .front {
            -webkit-border-radius:8px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color:yellow;
            z-index: 9870;
        }

        .element .back {
            -webkit-border-radius:8px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
            z-index: 0;
            border: 1px solid red;
            background-color:green;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://raw.github.com/pwhisenhunt/jquery.transform/master/jquery.transform.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var temp = false;
            $(".element").click(function(){
                if(temp == false){
                    $(this).transform("setAnimationDuration", 1).transform("rotateY", 180);
                    $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
                    button = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", "button").css({ width: 200, height: 50, backgroundColor:"blue" });
                    button.click(function(){
                        console.log("Clicking");
                    });
                    temp = true;
                    $(this).append(button);
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="element">
        <figure class="front"></front>
        <figure class="back"></front>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**[A JSFiddle Example of the Problem - Can be found HERE!](http://jsfiddle.net/7AbWe/)**

Comment: Would you mind putting together a http://jsfiddle.net/ for this?

Comment: I edited the question to include an example of the problem, you'll have to download the jquery plugin for the 3d transformations. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, working on a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/theredhead/rZT2k/)

Comment: hi i am facing the same problem in rotation of overlapping divs. can you help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that you are missing a container (in much the same way I was missing it).

see [the official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#samplecode/CardFlip/Introduction/Intro.html)

it's not the outer element being flipped, but a wrapper inside it. that in turn causes one of two divs to be displayed (and the transition to occur)

Comment: Awesome link! Does the rotating without a problem. Why didn't he accept this answer?!

Answer (score 11):

I know this reply is a bit too late for most of us here, but I ran into this problem earlier today, and none of the replies helped me solve it.

Solution by [@kristiankeane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13144326/1113260) made the other half non-clickable. I was [using a container for the wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8458637/1113260) as well. Turns out, it's an odd bug in webkit, and I was able to fix it and make 100% of the element clickable by changing transform: rotateY(180deg) to transform: rotateY(-180deg)

It's really odd, and I don't know how it worked, but it did. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same issue, was able to fix it by slightly changing the parent rotation when flipped - I changed

```
`.flip-holder.flipped {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
}`
```

to

```
`$.flip-holder.flipped {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180.5deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180.5deg);
transform: rotateY(180.5deg);
}`
```

and the entire backface (plus overflowed elements positioned absolutely) were now clickable, and the browser did not render the extra 0.5deg of rotation so text and images are clear.

Answer (score 3):

Translate both front and back just a little bit and they won't overlap.

Example:

```
    .element .front {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
    }

    .element .back {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
    }
```

Comment: I found this to be the only solution that works. The key though is to only apply the translateZ to the card that you've just flipped to the back and only when it's flipped. That way you won't be affected by the fuzzy rendering that the translateZ would otherwise cause.

Answer (score 1):

If your flip card structure is like this:

```
<div class="flipcard">
    <div class="flipcard-front">
    </div>
    <div class="flipcard-back">
    </div>
</div>
```

then add this to your CSS:

```
.flipcard:hover {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.flipcard-back:hover {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

could It be (and I'm just speculating) that you should use a live or delegate event bind instead of the regular. I'm speculating the click event maybe 'remembers' some how the original div position without the rotating.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be. I've tried both live() and delegate with the same results...Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

After all tricks as rotate to back and rotate to 180.5 and other...
problem fixed only the following way:
When the rotation ends - create new element, clone html from rotated element, and insert new element instead of old